# Prove that $g$ is differentiable and that $g'$ is not differentiable at $0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image]

For part ($c$) I assume I have to show that the limits from above and below are equal? I am having trouble doing this though...

I get limit as $h$ tends to $0$ of ( $(4-h^2)^{0.5}$ - ($4^{0.5}$) )/$h$ but i do not know what to do with this, I think I may be doing it wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you added what you know about derivatives: Are you intended to use the chain rule everywhere except $x = 0$, or is the intent really that you use difference quotients...? Thank you.

Comment: I think we are supposed to use difference quotients but I am unsure...

Comment: Surely you know how to differentiate $2.$ That is the right derivative of $g$ at $0.$. And you know how to differentiate $\sqrt {4-x^2}.$ That derivative at $0$ will be the left derivative of $g$ at $0.$

Comment: okay, so that shows that g is differentiable, so I get different g' for x between -2 and 0 and x between 0 and 2, and to show g' is continuous at x_0=0 you show that they both equal 0, and to show its not differentiable I get that one of them is 0 and the other is -1/2? so not equal, so not differentiable? (sorry if that makes no sense, I find it difficult to write nicely on here)